# Chrome bug: css positioning incorrectly resizing container

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have the following HTML and CSS in a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SyKfm/)**:

```
<div class="MyBox">

    <div class="TopText">text here</div>    
    <div class="MyText">text</div>
    <div class="MyText">text</div>
    <div class="MyText">text</div>
    <div class="MyText">text</div>
    <div class="MyText">text</div>
    <div class="OtherText1">text1</div>
    <div class="OtherText2">text2</div>

​</div>
```

```css
.MyBox{
    padding:10px 10px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:10px 0px;
    ​border:5px solid black;}

.TopText{clear:right;}

.MyText{
    float:left;
    margin:10px 10px;}

.OtherText1{
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    margin:10px 10px;}

.OtherText2{
    float:left;
    margin:10px 0px 10px 50px;}
```

The divs of class MyBox need to be absolutely positioned. The problem is that the MyBox div sizes itself nicely when I don't have the OtherText divs in the container div but if I have these divs then it seems like the container div resizes itself by adding their width. **This problem seems to be only visible in Chrome**, which is rather weird.

How do I fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insane trick: add `float:left` to the absolute positioned `MyBox` for extra shrinkwrap power:

http://jsfiddle.net/SyKfm/2/

```
.MyBox {
    position:absolute;
    float: left;
```

There was a similar question a few day ago, but it had an abs. positioned max-width div:

[Div smart width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163944/div-smart-width/)

Comment: Wow indeed! Is it a Chrome bug? That'd be quite something for this usually well-behaved browser!

Comment: Reduced test case with another solution (use `clear:both` instead of `clear:left`): http://jsfiddle.net/SyKfm/13/

Answer (score 0):

why it's happening? I don't really know, but how can you fix it? I know it's not optimal, but you can add a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` before the 2 'othertexts'.  Maybe the problem has something to do with having clear and float in the same element? dunno.